# Characterization of simply connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $D$ be a domain (open and connected) in $\mathbb{C}$. Then show that the following are equivalent:

(1) $D$ is simply connected (in homotopy sense);

(2) $\left( \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}\right)\setminus D$ is connected;

(3) For each holomorphic function $f$ on $D$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in D$, there exists a holomorphic function $g$ on $D$ such that $f = e^g$;

(4) For each holomorphic function $f$ on $D$ such that $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in D$ and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a holomorphic function $h$ on $D$ such that $f = h^n.$

How unique are functions $g, h$ ?

I am not sure how to do $(1) \rightarrow (2), (2) \rightarrow (3)$ and $(4) \rightarrow (1)$. Actually in $(2)$, I think that $g := \log (f)$ which is not unique since $e^z$ is a periodic function. I am not sure why $(2)$ is needed to define $g := \log (f)$ in $(3)$.

Comment: (2) is not a statement

Comment: For (3), there is one such function $g$ for each integer multiple of $2\pi$. In (4), for each $n$ there are $n$ such functions $h$.

Comment: Sorry for (2), I miss "connected".

Comment: For (2), you mean that the complement of $D$ in $\Bbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show that $(1) \iff (2)$. This part is purely topological.

If $D$ is simply connected, we can carry a homotopy on 2-sphere such that this region is compressed to a point on sphere. $\mathbb{S}^2 \backslash \{pt\}$ is connected, so is $(\mathbb{C}\backslash D)\cup \{ \infty \} $.

Ont the other hand, If $D$ is not simply connected, we can take a non-trivial loop inside $D$ so that the region bounded by this loop doesn't lie inside $D$ completely. That is, some point in the region is disconnected from $\infty$. So $(\mathbb{C}\backslash D)\cup \{ \infty \} $ is not connected.

(1) $\implies$ (3) or (4) is a direct use of complex logarithm. The function $g$ in
$$ f(z) = e^{g(z)} $$
is not unique unless you fix $g(z_0) \in \exp^{-1}(f(z_0))$ for a point $z_0 \in D$.

For (3) or (4) $\implies$ (1), it is again by topological argument. Assume $0$ is not in $D$, we can get $f: D \to \mathbb{C}^*$ as the inclusion map. If $\gamma$ is a loop in $D$, for example in the case of (3), 
$$ [\gamma] = f_*[\gamma] = exp_* \circ g_*[\gamma] = 0 $$
So, $\gamma$ is trivial in $\pi_1(D)$. Exactly, $\pi_1(D) = 0$.

Comment: I can not recognize the importance of (1) imply (3), that is, I am not sure why the domain must be simply connected. I suppose that to prove (3), I can define $g := log (f)$ and show appropriately that the result holds.

Comment: The problem is that $\log f$ doesn't mean $log \circ f$. 
$$ \log f : D \to \mathbb{C} $$
This function has nothing to do with $f(D)$, which can be not simply connected in nature. When $D$ is simply connected, we can define $g$ by $$ g(z) = g(z_0) + \int_\gamma \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)} dw $$ for some path $\gamma$ from $z_0$ to $z$, with prescribed $z_0$. It is well-defined because we have independence of path on this integral. It comes from the fact that $D$ is simply connected.

Comment: I should really point out that for (3) $\implies$ (1), the inclusion $f: D \to \mathbb{C}^*$ is not always non-trivial on fundamental groups. You do need a translation map to make sure it is non-trivial.