# Simply connected domains and complex logarithms

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, analyticity, proof-explanation

While studying Complex Analysis from my professor's notes I came across the following theorem.

> A demain $D$ in the complex plane is simply connected if and only if any analytic function $f(z)$ on $D$ that does not vanish at any point of $D$ has an analytic logarithm on $D$. For the proof, consider the function
>
> $$
> G(z) = \int_{z_0}^{z} \frac{f'(w)}{f(w)} \, dw \;\; \text{with} \ f(z) \neq 0.
> $$

It is my understanding that the proof of this theorem is very useful for problems/exercises involving the existence of analytic functions on simply connected domains.

---

I am looking for a complete proof of this theorem (with no "shortcuts", if possible) which will allow me to understand the above theorem in detail.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183777/characterization-of-simply-connected-domain.

Comment: Have you consulted any textbooks on complex analysis to find the proof you desire?

Comment: @LeeMosher Both of the two textbooks I have (Churchill's and a greek one) do not cover this particular subject, unfortunately.

Comment: I believe you'll find it in Ahlfors' book "Complex Analysis".

Comment: "Foundations of Modern Analysis" by Jean Dieudonné (translation from French) is a great book on the subject of complex analysis.