# Is there a characterization of entire functions with image $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, entire-functions

Do we have a characterisation of entire functions with image $\Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$?

If not, is there an example of such a function that is not in the form of $\exp(g)$ for some entire function $g$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* If $f$ is never zero in $\mathbb C$, then $\frac{f'}{f}$ is entire and so has a primitive.

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is entire and $f(z) \ne 0$ for all $z$, then there is an entire $g$ such that $f=e^g$, since $ \mathbb C$ is simply connected.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the argument?

Comment: This is a consequence of the following well-known Theorem: Let $G$ be aregion in $ \mathbb C$. Then $G$ is simply connected if and only if each holomorphic and zero-free function on $G$ has a holomorphic logarithm on $G$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183777/characterization-of-simply-connected-domain