# Connection between a branch of logarithm and simply connected domains

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Currently, I am trying to solve the following exercise involving the definition of branches of logarithms:

> **Def**: Let $D \subseteq \mathbb C$ be a domain, we call every continuous function $L : D \to \Bbb C$ a branch of the logarithm if it satisfies
> $$
> e^{L(z)} = z \quad \forall z \in G.
> $$

> **Exercise**: Let $D \subseteq \mathbb C$ be a simply connected domain not containing zero, show that there exists a branch of the logarithm.

**Solution**: As long as we can take the function
$$
z \mapsto L(z) = \ln(|z|) + i \arg(z), 
$$
where $\ln$ is the $\log_e$ that one knows from calculus and one takes the following branch of $\operatorname{Arg}$ given by $\arg(z) = \{\theta \in [-\pi,\pi) : z = |z| e^{i \theta}\}.$ Then it sufficies to show that the function above is continuous. Indeed, $\ln$ and the absolute values are, so it is only left to show that $\arg$ is. By the definition of $\arg(z)$, one has
$$
\arg(z) = \theta \iff x+iy = |x+iy| e^{i \theta} \iff x = r \cos(\theta) \text{ and } y = r \sin(\theta).
$$
Using elementary geometry one then can calculate explicitly
$$
\arg(x+iy) = \begin{cases}
\arctan(y/x) &, x > 0, \\
\pi + \arctan(y/x) &, x < 0 \text{ and } y \geq 0, \\
-\pi + \arctan(y/x) &, x < 0 \text{ and } y < 0, \\
+\pi/2 &, x = 0 \text{ and } y > 0, \\
-\pi/2 &, x =0 \text{ and } y < 0. \\
\end{cases}$$
So in order to show that $\arg(\cdot)$ is continuous now it sufficies to take any sequence $(z_n)$ that converges to some $z \in D$ and show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{arg}(z_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \operatorname{arg}(x_n+iy_n) = \operatorname{arg}(x+iy) =\operatorname{arg}(z).
$$
But using the rewriting and different cases from above this seems to hold true, since $\arctan$ from above seems continuous but now we have not used the simply connectedness yet, so I am missing something obvious? (Note: My definition only needs continuity).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is not simply connected, and neither is an annulus. I would advise you to review some of the definitions (also I am not sure what $\mathbb{C}^*\setminus\{0\}$ would be).

Comment: [Characterization of simply connected domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1183777/721644)

Comment: I believe there is $i$ missing, but I didn't edit it: $$\arg(z)=-\color{red}i\ln\left(\frac{z}{|z|}\right).$$ Also, $\ln z=\ln|z|+\color{red}i\arg(z).$

Comment: I made the according changes

Comment: Your choice of argument won't always work, it is not defined and cannot be continuously defined on $(-\infty,0)$

Comment: Allright, I see that seems quite obvious when one thinks about the principle branch of logarithm where one needs to cut out the ray $(-\infty,0)$ to avoid the discontinuity around the negative real axis for the argument. In the more general setting of more general domains, it seems possible to do this if there exists some ray $R_{\theta} := \{z \in \C : z = r e^{i\theta} \; r \geq 0\} such that $G \cap R_{\theta} = \emptyset$, but this is somehow unsuitable for simply connected domains, so does one really needs to go to the generality that given as charactersiation of simply connected domain?